# How to pass javascript variable to php mysql select query?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

### I need to get the value of 'val' and to use it on the WHERE Clause of my MYSQL Query how can I do that? ##

```
<script>
   function myFunction(val) {
   alert("The input value has changed. The new value is: " + val);

   **var var1 = val;
   $.ajax({
        url: 'your_script.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {var1: javascript_var_1},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("success");
        }
    });**
```

> This where I put my ajax code.

```
   var ele = document.getElementById('insertHere');
   ele.innerHTML = '<input class="form-control" name="fullname" placeholder="Student Full Name"
   value="<?php 

      $var1 = $_POST['var1'];                                              


     $query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE studentID = '$var1' ";
     $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
     echo $row['fname'].' '.$row['mname'].' '.$row['lname'];



    ?>" readonly/>';



  }
 </script>
```

Comment: You can use AJAX/XHR or a simple `<form>`, whatever suits you best, to POST the variable to your PHP file.

Comment: I have tried ajax but its not working I do not know what's the problem.

Comment: Then show us the code that you tried and explain to us what exactly is "not working".

Comment: $.ajax({
            url: 'guardoffenses.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {var1: javascript_var_1},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("success");
            }
        });

Comment: Post it in the question, not as a comment... And don't forget to include the error message.

Comment: then i post it using php.... $var1 = $_POST['var1'];

Comment: What do you mean by "then I post it using PHP"?

Comment: I edited my post please could you take a look again?

Comment: Look at the linked question and try to get a grasp of the concepts "server-side" and "client-side"

Comment: I have my php code inside a script will that be okay?